# cloud run with trigger pubsub some time retrigger again (message twice)

Tags: c#, triggers, cloud, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-run

I have cloud run service that handle pubsub trigger. After deploy and after cold restart when the Cloud Run functionality take about 8 sec to execute, i see the message running again.

Did someone see this events also? there are a solution for that ?

Comment: Are you trying to say Cloud Run is getting the request twice?

Comment: Did you try the container on your local environment and see if the issue occurs again or not?

Comment: I found how to fix it by raise ack deadline

Answer (score 2):

I find how to handle this problem, just raise the ack deadline value from 10s to 30s
this can do by:

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions update <subscription> --ack-deadline=30
```